# Why do Hadoop jobs need so many threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop, apache-pig

My understanding of Hadoop is that parallelism on each compute node is achieved by launching separate jvms for each core.

I observe that each jvm owns dozens of threads, leading to thousands of threads per node. I can't think of any reason to spawn so many threads. What's going on?

For example, here's a simple pig script that parses and filters some jsons:

```
/*
 * Get tweets with GPS
 */
REGISTER $JAR;

json_eb = LOAD '$IN_DIRS' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') as (json:map[]);

--parse json with twitter's library
parsed0 = FOREACH json_eb GENERATE  STRSPLIT(json#'id',':').$2 AS tweetId:chararray,
                                    STRSPLIT(json#'actor'#'id',':').$2 AS userId:chararray,
                                    json#'postedTime' AS postedTime:chararray,
                                    json#'geo'#'coordinates' AS gps:chararray;
parsed1 = FILTER parsed0 BY (gps IS NOT NULL);

STORE parsed1 INTO '$OUT_DIR' USING PigStorage();
```

I run this script and the mapred user starts up 33 processes on my node (I have 32 cores):

```
rfcompton@node19 ~> ps -u mapred | grep -v PID | wc -l
33
```

Looking at top:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                    
  484 mapred    39  16 1576m 362m  18m S 130.8  0.3   0:09.48 java                                                                                                                                      
32427 mapred    34  16 1664m 369m  18m S 122.2  0.3   0:08.67 java                                                                                                                                      
32694 mapred    36  16 1502m 239m  18m S 115.6  0.2   0:07.94 java                                                                                                                                      
32218 mapred    33  16 1669m 401m  18m S 114.6  0.3   0:10.29 java  
...
```

The jvms seem to have around 40 threads each:

```
rfcompton@node19 ~> cat /proc/484/status | grep Threads
Threads:    43
```

All together, mapred has over a thousand threads on a 32-core node:

```
rfcompton@node19 ~> ps -u mapred | grep -v PID | awk '{system("cat /proc/"$1"/status")}' | grep Threads | awk '{ SUM += $2} END { print SUM }'
1655
```

**edit:** After reading the relevant section in "Hadoop - The Definitive Guide" as suggested by Paul's answer, it appears that 40 threads is what I should expect. They exist to serve the output of the maps over HTTP to later stages of the job.

> The output file’s partitions are made available to the reducers over
>   HTTP. The number of worker threads used to serve the file partitions
>   is controlled by the task tracker.http.threads property—this setting
>   is per tasktracker, not per map task slot. The default of 40 may need
>   increasing for large clusters running large jobs.

Comment: Each JVM always has multiple threads running, such as the garbage collector and possibly I/O threads.

Comment: One of the many reasons is, that the Apache coders are not necessarily experts in what they do, they just happened to have a good idea and turned it into code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All hadoop implementations I've seen multithread heavily. Basically, most tasks that move work from map tasks into reducers are paralellized, as are map tasks and reduce tasks themselves.

Checking "Hadoop - The Definitive Guide", the author mentions a number of processes that are multithreaded. These include

1. Reducers have a small pool of "copier" threads to fetch map outputs in paralell.
2. Mappers themselves can be multithreaded (MultithreadedMapper)
3. DataNodes have threads to copy data on and off HDFS.

Depending on how your cluster is configured, you can have DataNodes and TaskTrackers on the same machine, and this can start to add up to a lot of threads.

I'd guess that heavy use of concurrency has significant performance benefits, and that's why the implementors have gone that route.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking through the relevant section of Hadoop - The Definitive Guide now, though I'm still a bit surprised by the number of threads.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Chrylis, the JVM have some GC threads and possibly other threads running.

When it comes to user applications, multiple threads can be very useful.

An example of this is a case where you open a file, read each line and then do some processsing. While the thread is reading from file, the CPU is usually not working much because it will spend most of it's time waiting for the slow harddisk to return data. By using multiple threads, the CPU is utilized better. If your program used threads, some threads could be doing something useful while other threads are waiting for IO operations to complete.

I haven't used Hadoop, but I assume that when splitting the work, a node may in fact be running multiple jobs for this reason. They probably also contain some threads for coordinating with other parts of the cluster.